# Need to cut file name into part after some word

Tags: text-processing, filenames

How can I get `hhmmss` from a file name like this:  `abcdeProfileList_YYYYMMDDhhmmss.xml` also i need to add : in between the hhmmss.
like hh:mm:ss

Comment: You should give an example of an actual file name. But this looks like a mission for `sed` or `cut`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in *.xml; do TMP=${i%.xml}; echo ${TMP:(-6)};done
```

Comment: You forgot to add the `:`s in between... but still, much better than the others.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls abcdeProfileList_YYYYMMDDhhmmss.xml | cut -d '.' -f 1 | grep -o '......$'
```

But I'm assuming a lot.

Your question needs to be more specific.

Comment: `cut` can cut at character count: `cut -c 26-31`

Comment: I'm guessing op wants to do this for many files which may not always have the same number of characters in them.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "abcdeProfileList_YYYYMMDDhhmmss.xml" | awk -F"_" '{print $2}'|awk -F"." '{print $1}'| cut -c 9-14
```

Comment: echo "abcdeProfileList_YYYYMMDDhhmmss.xml" | awk -F"[._]" '{print substr($2,length($2)-5,6)}'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Bash environment:

```
jvc@BlueBuilder:~$ filename=abcdeProfileList_YYYYMMDDhhmmss.xml
jvc@BlueBuilder:~$ timetag=`echo "${filename/.xml/}" | cut -f2 -d_`
jvc@BlueBuilder:~$ echo "${timetag:8:2}:${timetag:10:2}:${timetag:12:2}"
hh:mm:ss
```

If you have multiple files - again Bash:

```
ls -1 *.xml | cut -f1 -d. | cut -f2 -d_ | while read timetag; do 
  echo "${timetag:8:2}:${timetag:10:2}:${timetag:12:2}"; 
done
```